# ArgumentError('The object \'deviceInfo' is missing the property: deviceId'); How do I solve this?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-sql-database, dashboard, azure-iot-hub

I am working with Azure IoT Hub and trying to retrieve real devices (not simulated) which are connected to our workplace Hub. The project is that we're creating a company dashboard to display and edit various aspects of devices from our IoT Hub. I am an intern, so this is truly my first time ever doing ANYTHING with IoT Hub, so please forgive naivety. I am testing just to send basic information about devices in a "registry.create" function, but I keep receiving aforementioned error. Also, our database is Azure SQL.

Here is my code for the section. Only necessary code is posted:

```
var iothub = require('azure-iothub');
var connectionString = '<Our connection string here>';
var registry = iothub.Registry.fromConnectionString(connectionString);

...

const device = {
    deviceId: registry.deviceId,
    devStatus: registry.status,
    connStatus: registry.connectionState
}

registry.create(device, function(err, deviceInfo, res) {
    if (err) {
        registry.get(device.deviceId, printDeviceInfo);
        console.log(device.deviceId);
    }
    if (deviceInfo.deviceId) {
        printDeviceInfo(err, deviceInfo.deviceId, res)
    }
});

function printDeviceInfo(err, deviceInfo, res) {
    if (deviceInfo) {
        console.log('Device ID: ' + deviceInfo.deviceId);
        console.log('Connection state: ' + deviceInfo.connStatus)
    }
}
```

Here is database model for devices:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const Device = sequelize.define('devices', {
        deviceId: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            required: true
        },
        devStatus: {
            type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: true
        },
    });
    return Device;
}
```

Not sure how much assistance can be suggested, but anything is appreciated. Not much is online about this error (literally two pages in Google and neither were similar to my specific problem)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see the [source code of IOT hub SDKs](https://github.com/Eclo/azure-iot-sdks/blob/978ecdad808ac1a301bc483858c0ea169c940342/node/service/lib/registry.js#L104), you will find that *the create method shall throw `ArgumentError` if the first argument does not contain a deviceId property*:

[image]

So, your `deviceId` property is not populated. [create(DeviceDescription, HttpResponseCallback)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-iothub/registry?view=azure-node-latest#create_DeviceDescription__HttpResponseCallback_Device__) creates a new device identity on an IoT hub. You will have to provide a value to it. [Registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-iothub/registry?view=azure-node-latest#create_DeviceDescription__HttpResponseCallback_Device__) does not provide those properties you have used in your code. Refer [this](https://gist.github.com/jsturtevant/1d383c682d0d2c6422218bac4b7f5c8d#file-wipregisterfunction-js) sample for proper usage of `registry.create`. And, I would recommend you to read [Understand the identity registry in your IoT hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-identity-registry).

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Can you explain this some more? How would I "populate" it?

Comment: Does it help you?

Comment: Hi, yes it has mostly helped. I was able to log all deviceIDs into the console, but am having a bit of trouble to send to Postman now. I keep receiving error "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client". My screenshot of my updated code and my console log is here: 
https://imgur.com/a/sprvtLy


I can give you "accepted answer" anyways, but I'd really like a follow-up, as I know that it is super close now. As you can see under the last line of SQL queries and before "_http_outgoing...", two devices show in the console before the error. Postman displays one.

Comment: Console logged all devices before I put "res.send" (to display in Postman, of course), but after that, I received error which is mentioned in my previous comment now.

Comment: Pls check if you are setting headers after you sent request to client.